# Typos in "the reasons changes"?

Tags: subject-verb-agreement

Excerpted from [chronicle.com](http://chronicle.com/article/Is-Philosophy-Obsolete-/145837/):

> **The reasons** by which we make our behavior coherent to ourselves **changes** together with our view of who has reasons coming to them.

It says "the reasons changes", is it a typo of "the reasons change"?

Comment: It looks like a typo to me.  The writer might have lost his train of thought while writing the sentence and forgotten whether he used the singular or the plural.

Comment: Author is matching **changes** to **behaviour** not to **reasons**. Philosophy not English major...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's most definitely an error. Good catch. I have to add that, even with the grammar corrected, I find the entire sentence incomprehensible. But - I haven't looked at it in context.

Answer (score 1):

IMO, this is not so much a typo as a grammar flub - one sadly common among native speakers.

The writer has matched the verb form to the closest noun, "behavior", rather than to the subject, "reasons".